# Почему на WP сайте код (плагин AJAX Load More) не грузит страницы исходя из языка?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wp-plugin

Код для плагина **AJAX Load More** должен грузить в бесконечном скролле , при подходе к нижней границе страницы - страницы исходя **из полученного языка материнской** (текущей загруженной страницы).

Но почему-то грузит страницы как и без кода, то есть **на произвольных языках**.

Например **на португальской** странице плагин грузит страницы у которых в url не на **португальском**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на **ru** странице плагин грузит страницы у которых в url **не на русском** *(еще не доделал на ru замену):*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, я есть еще не доделал что если страница на **ru** , чтоб он грузил внизу страницы на **ru**, но это не суть важно, т.к. даже на том же **pt**
языке который вроде я сделал, он не подсовывает в загрузку строго на **pt** языке.

**код:**

```js
console.log('Начало работы скрипта Ajax Load More...');

// Получаем путь текущего URL
var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
console.log('Текущий URL:', currentUrl);

// Регулярное выражение для определения языкового кода
var languageRegex = /^\/(zh|tr|pt|ja|it|id|fr|es|en|de)\//; 
var languagePath = currentUrl.match(languageRegex) ? currentUrl.match(languageRegex)[1] : '';

if (!languagePath) {
    languagePath = 'ru';
    console.log('Языковой путь: ru');
} else {
    console.log('Языковой путь:', languagePath);
}

// Функция для изменения запроса Ajax Load More перед отправкой
window.almOnLoad = function(alm) {
    console.log('Перед отправкой запроса Ajax Load More');
    // Если языковой код присутствует и не 'ru', модифицируем путь для AJAX-запроса
    if(languagePath !== 'ru') {
        alm.ajaxurl = alm.ajaxurl.replace('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', '/' + languagePath + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php');
        console.log('Модифицированный путь AJAX-запроса:', alm.ajaxurl);
    } else {
        // Если код 'ru' или отсутствует, используем стандартный путь AJAX-запроса
        console.log('Стандартный путь AJAX-запроса для русского языка.');
    }
};

console.log('Скрипт Ajax Load More настроен.');
```

Comment: Каким образом у Вас реализована мультиязычность? `Код для плагина` -- плагин самопальный? Так-то наверное следовало бы приложить PHP код.

Comment: @Simon решение это просто отдельные страницы\папки созданные независимо друг от друга и существующие независимо, называйте это как хотите, это сути это не меняет.

Есть Url https://transscreen.ru/news11043/ это значит страница (page) на русском языке т. к. в нём нету ru.
Есть вообще другая независимая страница, у которой другой url вот такой: https://transscreen.ru/pt/news11043/ она на португальском языке/ узнать на каком она языке не трудно, в url есть pt, этим и должен руководствоваться плагин AJAX Load More когда подсовывает вниз материнской страницы загружая другие рандомные страницы

Comment: @Simon Иными словами.... очень простая хотелка у меня, например у меня грузится страница https://transscreen.ru/pt/luboytext , значит внизу нее должен плагин AJAX Load More грузить вообще любые страницы с сайта transscreen.ru у которых в url вот такой патерн:
https://transscreen.ru/pt/luboytext

где luboytext- Любой текст)))

Comment: Это не объясняет того как на данный момент Вы загружаете эти записи/страницы.

Comment: У Вас в приведенном скрипте есть кусок `alm.ajaxurl = alm.ajaxurl.replace('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', '/' + languagePath + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php');`, но если посмотрите в инструментах разработчика в браузере в вкладке Network, запрос все равно уходит на `transscreen.ru/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, даже если в URL присутствует `pt`.

Comment: А как ты ВП объяснил, что `pt` в урле  - это какой-то другой язык? Не майся фигнёй, используй плагины мультиязычности.

Comment: @SeVlad я не объяснил ничего ему, еще раз повторюсь:
 решение это просто отдельные страницы\папки созданные независимо друг от друга и существующие независимо, называйте это как хотите, это сути это не меняет. Есть Url transscreen.ru/news11043 это значит страница (page) на русс яз т. к. в нём нету ru. Есть вообще другая независимая страница, у которой другой url вот такой: transscreen.ru/pt/news11043 она на порту языке/ узнать на каком она языке не трудно, в url есть pt, этим и должен руководствоваться плагин ALM когда подсовывает вниз материнской страницы загружая другие рандомные страницы

Comment: Не надо нам по 10 раз одно и тоже писать. Ты ВП для начала объясни как он должен отличать твои "языки". Только тогда он сможет формировать нужный тебе запрос в БД. Но это не значит что такие костыли будут понимать другие плагины. Еще раз - использую нормальные решения - плагины мультиязычности и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: @SeVlad но тут не в языках дело, а в выборочной загрузке страниц , то есть нужно загружать страницы у которых есть такой же паттерн в url как у материнской страницы. Вот я и написал кастомный js код который должен заставлять внизу материнской страницы грузить необходимые мне, но он почему-то не работает и я сюда пришел чтоб мне помогли с кодом.

Comment: @MikhailEliseev тот JS код который Вы здесь привели, не слишком полезен и имеет довольно посредственное отношение к вопросу, потому и не понятно, чего Вы с этим от нас ждете и в чем конкретная проблема. В Вашем коде Вы просто извлекаете по определенному паттерну типа как локаль и затем Вы вешаете колбек на событие, который меняет `ajaxurl`, все остальное покрыто завесой тайны. На черта Вам вообще нужно `pt` и так далее, если Вам уже известен ID страницы, таким образом можно получить ее parent страницу и выводить дочерние.

Comment: Но в целом Ваша логика по прежнему неизвестна. Ох, ну и наверное стоило указать что Вы пользуетесь плагином [WordPress Infinite Scroll – Ajax Load More](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/), а то пришлось в хрустальный шар заглядывать.

Comment: В конктексте плагина, которым Вы пользуетесь, почему Вы думаете что это должно каким-то образом решить проблему: `alm.ajaxurl = alm.ajaxurl.replace('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', '/' + languagePath + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php');`?

Comment: @MikhailEliseev может всё-же вдумаешься в слова "запрос в БД" (в тч и подумай над формированием критериев запроса)?.. ну ходи по гряблям - твоё право. _Плагинофобия лечится изучением матчасти_ (С)Я :)